# I cannot get the PID for this "${@}" 1> >(2log) 2> >(2log2scr | tee >&2)

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I searched a bit on how to do this, but I cannot find a solution.
I am using process substitution cause of necessity.
I want to wait for all the processing to finish before proceeding.

How do I get the PID of my **'runner' FUNCTION below** so I can wait for it?

Basically what it does is execute, then log the stdout, then log errors & errors to stdout. Works well except for the out of sequence responses.

```
"${@}" 1> >(2log) 2> >(2log2scr | tee >&2) 
pid=????                                      # <<< HERE
while [ -e /proc/"$pid" ]; do sleep 0.1; done # <<< HERE
```

I tried things like the following but does not work:

1. pid=$(exec sh -c "${@}" 1> >(2log) 2> >(2log2scr | tee >&2) )
2. this works partially - it breaks my EVAL:

> ```
> >     runner success &
> >     while [ -e /proc/$! ]; do sleep 0.1; done
> ```
>
> OUTPUTS
>
> ```
> started running
>
> FAILURE: **** 4.4.19(1)-release ****
>  finished running
>
> EVAL IS:
> ```

Your help is appreciated.

The full script follows if you need it for testing:

```
#!/bin/bash
logfile='test.log'
logprep() {
    local in=$(cat)
    in=$(echo "$in" | perl -pe 's/\**//smig')   # for proc subst
    # Return prepped string
    echo -e "preped for logging: '$in'"
}   
2log() {
    local in=$(cat)
    if [ "$in" != '' ]; then 
        echo -e "$in" | logprep >>"$logfile"    # out to logfile
    fi
    return 0    
}
2log2scr() {
    local in=$(cat)
    # 2scr
    if [ "'$in'" != '' ]; then echo -e "$in"; fi

    # 2log
    if [ "$in" != '' ]; then 
        echo -e "$in" > >(logprep >>"$logfile") # out to logfile
    fi
    return 0
}
runner () {
    echo -e "started running\n"
    "${@}" 1> >(2log) 2> >(2log2scr | tee >&2)      # <<< RUNNER
    #while [ -e /proc/15435 ]; do sleep 0.1; done   # <<< HERE
    echo -e "finished running\n"
}
success() {
    eval 'version=$(echo "SUCCESS: **** ${BASH_VERSION} ****")'
    echo -e "$version"; return 0
}
failure() {
    eval 'version=$(echo "FAILURE: **** ${BASH_VERSION} ****")'
    echo -e "$version" 1>&2; return 64
}

runner success  # to test a successful command
runner failure  # to test a command that errs

echo "EVAL IS: $version"
```

Comment: The script should already wait for it to finish before moving to the next line unless it is being sent to the background somehow.

Comment: its out of sequence

Comment: It's hard to successfully get stdout and stderr output properly interleaved as you would see it in your terminal: stdout is buffered but stderr is not, I think.

Answer (score 1):

The pid of a background process can be retrieved from the $! environment variable if it has been put into the background (via adding a & to the end of your command), i.e.

```
my-cmd &
echo $!
```

Another option you could explore is using $$ (pid of current shell) within the executed shell, e.g.

```
exec sh -c 'echo $$ > t.pid && sleep 10' &
echo $!  # <-- pid of spawned shell
pid=$(cat t.pid)  # <-- pid of execed process in shell
```

Something like this will give you the pid in a temporary file named t.pid

Comment: Hey jjj thanks for you nice comment. I tried your suggestion (my-cmd &
echo $!) already but for some reason it breaks my EVAL. see my comment section on what I tried.

Comment: Glad you got it working - thanks for posting your final result

Answer (score 0):

The only way I got this working without breaking my EVAL was this:

```
runner () {
    echo -e "started running\n"
    "${@}" 1> >(2log) 2> >(2log2scr | tee >&2) 
    while [ -e /proc/$! ]; do sleep 0.1; done
    echo -e "$pid finished running\n"
}
```

The difference here is that I am just plainly accessing `$!` without any prior requirements.
All suggestions everywhere mention that $! is accessed if we call our routine like so:

```
my-cmd &
echo $!
```

It seems that this is not a requirement and that we can plainly access `$!` after any complex   routine such as `"${@}" 1> >(2log) 2> >(2log2scr | tee >&2)` **without using the '&' anywhere**

Comment: I wonder if `$!` is the pid of the stderr process substitution. That seems like it would be the last background process created.